# Getting the body of an https response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a newbie to nodejs, and I'm having a weird problem trying to get my response's body. well, for printing out the body we might do something like this, right? :

```
var https = require('https');
var request = https.get('https://teamtreehouse.com/arshankhanifar.json',function(response){
    //print the data

    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk){
      console.log('BODY : ' + chunk); // Prints the body, no problem.
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});
```

With the above code, I can print out the body, which is supposed to be a string containing a JSON file, but the problem is that when I try to save it in a variable called body, when I print that, nothing shows up! :

```
var https = require('https');
var request = https.get('https://teamtreehouse.com/arshankhanifar.json',function(response){
    //save the data in a variable
    var body = '';

    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk){
      body += chunk;
    });

    console.log(body); // prints nothing! 
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log('No more data in response.');

    });
});
```

I hope my question is clear enough. Please ask for clarification if it's ambiguous.

Comment: Move `console.log(body);` inside the `on('end'...` function

Comment: yo thanks! you loyal! you smart!

Comment: `body += chunk` not `body += data`; you also need to log it in the correct callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing body variable before `data` got triggered.

Try like below.

```
var https = require('https');
var request = https.get('https://teamtreehouse.com/arshankhanifar.json',function(response){
    //save the data in a variable
    var body = '';

    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk){
      body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log(body); // prints nothing! 
      console.log('No more data in response.');

    });
});
```

Refer:
https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

Comment: Accept the answer if your problem solved or let us know what issue is currently exist.